# How can I make a progress circle

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, android-drawable

What would be the best way to make this circle in android? I don't want to learn OpenGL just to draw a simple progress circle (ring), but if there's no other way I will. Before start, I want to ask you guys, what do you think. I'm open to all kind of suggestions on how to make this.

[image: An embossed circle, blue over half way around, showing \"69%\" in the middle.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `ProgressBar` widget built into Android, that by default renders as a circle.

You can use an `ImageView` backed by a `ShapeDrawable` that is a ring, with a gradient sweep fill of your choosing.

You can create 100 PNG files, one per percentage, and use those, perhaps via a `LevelListDrawable`.

You can draw the whole thing yourself as a custom `View` using the `Canvas`.

There are probably other alternatives as well, but this should get you going.

Comment: This is the way i choose, but i will wait for another replays, because i don't want to draw 100 png images. I just want to use more code and lass images if is possible.

Comment: @VasilValchev: Then go with the first, second, or fourth options above.

Comment: 1st method - no custum re-size                                      2th method cant draw a circle but not circle arc                     3rd method to large data                                             4th method is the way to do it

Comment: @VasilValchev: "2th method cant draw a circle but not circle arc" -- false. You can certainly draw a circle (`ring`) with `ShapeDrawable`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Progress/Styled/res/drawable/progress_circular.xml

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not too hard using SVG, check out Leandro Linares' [progress circle example](https://github.com/llinares/ring-progress-bar)

Comment: Ty, but i have a costume view for drawing this object, it was easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Tanks to @CommonsWare, here it is my code example

```
public class SampleView extends View {

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Canvas canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        // smooths
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        p.setStrokeWidth(5);
        // opacity
        //p.setAlpha(0x80); //

        RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 100, 80);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, p);
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true, p);
    }
}
```