# Android progress bar fill

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, gradient, radial

I want a loading bar in a circle shape. I want to fill it with an integer i tried this

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:indeterminateDrawable="@xml/progress" >
    </ProgressBar>
```

progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360" >

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="8"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dip"
        android:width="48dip" />

    <gradient

        android:centerY="0.50"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:gradientRadius="20"
        android:type="radial"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

and in my activity

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            bar.setProgress(50);
            bar.setMax(100);
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

The Circle stays black. If i set the gradient type to sweep, the circle fills with startcolor black and endcolor white.. and it constantly repeats.

But I want the circle to be filled once.. so it starts black and fills white; only 1 time..

Is this possible?

I want to reach this result:

http://ultimateprogrammingtutorials.blogspot.be/2013/02/how-to-draw-circular-progress-bar-in.html

Comment: should we guess the question or will u ask what u want here??

Comment: pls read my post again, i edited.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar) is one good example of CircularProgressBar, As per your requirement Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to do this:
https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

There are many similar questions on stackoverflow:

1. [How can I make a progress circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875678/how-can-i-make-progress-circle)
2. [Circular progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222239/circle-progressbar)
3. [Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)
4. [How To Make Circle Custom Progress Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688117/how-to-make-circle-custom-progress-bar-in-android)